# How can set an inbuilt timer in RStudio to execute snippets of code?

Tags: r, time, automation, rstudio

I have some code in Rstudio which sends an API request to Google Big Query to run a saved query. Then my script downloads the data back to RStudio to be modelled to a machine learning model.

Its a lot of medical data and I would like some of the process to be even more automated than before.

```
tags<-read.csv('patient_health_codes.csv',stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
tags<-tail(tags, 6)
```

this section takes a CSV to iterate over patient health groups (such as Eczema is 123456) - Section 1

```
MD2DS="2018-07-20" 
MD2DE="2018-07-20"
```

This section above fills in date periods for the query execution function - Section 2

```
sapply(health_tags$ID, function(x) query_details (MD2_date_start=MD2SE,    
                                                  MD2_date_end=MD2DE,                                                      
                                                Sterile_tag=as.character(x)))
```

This section executes the query on google big query and iterates over all the different patient groups in x i.e Eczema, Asthma, Allergy Group, and so on. -Section 3

```
project <- "private-health-clinic"
bq_table=paste0('[private-health-clinic:medical.london_',Sterile_tag,']')
sql =paste0('SELECT * FROM ', bq_table)
```

This section names each table after its patient group - section 4

```
data <- query_exec(sql, project = project, max_pages = Inf)
write.csv(data, file =paste0("medical_", Sterile_tag, ".csv"))
```

This code downloads and writes the big query table as a CSV on RStudio - Section 5

My question is, how do I tell RStudio when someone executes section 3 after 1 hour in real time please execute section 4 then 5 mins after execute section 5.

In advance thank you for the help I'm not an R expert!

Answer (score 0):

Just add this after section 3:

`Sys.sleep(3600)`

And after section 4, add:

`Sys.sleep(300)`

Comment: interesting! is there a way to say execute section after BQ is done with section 3? so its dynamically done?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Isn't R still running while big query is? If so you can just run all lines at once without any sleep commands in between.

Comment: @stacker `data <- query_exec(sql, project = project, max_pages = Inf)` is the line of code that may take some time (it is executing the sql query in Google Big Query. I think you may want to highlight all The lines of code you want to run, and execute it all at once (In R, the next line will not run until the current line is complete, even if it takes a long time) - you can execute it by pressing control + enter when it's highlighted. You may not need Sys.sleep(). If you want to execute a query and then write the results as a csv, highlight both lines and run both - hope this helps?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how long it takes to execute that code, it might be worthwhile to use `Sys.sleep` for the desired amount of waiting time minus the time spent calculating, as follows:

```
t0 <- Sys.time()

# section 3

t1 <- Sys.time()
Sys.sleep(3600 - (t1 - t0))

# section 4

t2 <- Sys.time()
Sys.sleep(300 - (t2 - t1))

# section 5
```

Otherwise the waiting time will be added to the time spent running the sections.